# Android emulator launch shown HVF error in mac

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am unable to launch any emulators on Android Studio. When trying to launch an emulator, I get the following error when i rum emulator from terminal in mac:

```
emulator @Nexus_5X_API_25
HVF error: HV_NO_DEVICE
failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument
Failed to open the hax module
No accelerator found.
failed to initialize HAX: Operation not supported by device
```

Comment: Did it ever work or you're just getting started and it's the first time you install Android Studio and try running emulator? If first time - I'd first check if the Virtualization is enabled in your BIOS.

Comment: In my case it was disabled virtualisation. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan thanks, its working like a charm.